# Serial device is not detected by pi

Tags: usb, serial

I have a serial device connected to pi´s USB slot. The device is connected to the USB port though internally the USB interface is connected to a USB-to-UART bridge.For programming purposes this means that the interface appears as (virtual) serial interface (RS232). The driver is CP210x.
In the pi, I used modprobe cp210x to load the driver. 
lsmod lists cp210x

The name of the device is Rotor Gene. In windows system it is detected in port COM5. After I connect to the device,
dmesg gives:

```
     usbcore:registered new interface driver usbserial 
     usbcore:registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
     usbserial:USB Serial support registered for generic
     usbcore:registered new interface driver cp210x
     usbserial:USB Serial support registered for  cp210x
     usb 1-1.2: new full speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
     usb 1-1.2:New USB device found, idVendor=c0b8, idProduct=e007
     usb 1-1.2:New USB device strings, Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

     usb 1-1.2: Product: ROTOR-GENE
     usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs usb
     usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 120876
```

With the device plugged and not plugged, ls /dev/tty* lists the same ports.
There is no ttyUSB nor ttyS in the list.

Why the device is not attached to a port in my pi.

Comment: Are you looking for /dev/ttyUSB* ?  - the first one is usually /dev/ttyUSB0